# How to fetch one-to-many associated objects based on properties of both parent and child objects

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

I have a parent object named "Order" that has many child objects named "OrderLines".

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ORDER")
class Order {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "order_number")
    String orderId;

    @Column(name = "location_id")
    String locationId;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ORDER_LINES")
public class FulfilmentOrderLines {

  @ManyToOne(optional = false)
  @Id
  @JoinColumn(name = "order_number")
  private Order orderNumber;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "order_line_number", nullable = false)
  private String orderLineNumber;

  @Column(name = "status")
  private int status;
}
```

I have to fetch all the orders from a specific locationId that has at least one "OrderLine" with the status below a certain value(say 1000, meaning that these are in "OPEN" state).

I can fetch all the orders for a location first and then filter it based on the required status criteria. But this would mean that I will have to fetch all the orders for that location, even the closed ones and this could be bad for performance.

Is there a way I can fetch the required objects directly from DB using Spring Data JPA or Criteria API?

I'm using SQL server as DB.

Comment: Why not create a ORDER_DATAILS table with the needed information and map it.

Comment: Are you talking about creating another table? Why should we do that when this is certainly a many-to-one relation?

Answer (score 0):

I had to make a couple of changes, but this should work with Spring Data JPA. First, move the key out from FulfilmentOrderLines into its own object to make an embedded ID.

```
@Embeddable
public class FulfilmentOrderLinesKey implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_number")
    private Order orderNumber;

    @Column(name = "order_line_number", nullable = false)
    private String orderLineNumber;
}
```

Then update FulfilmentOrderLines to reference that.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ORDER_LINES")
public class FulfilmentOrderLines {

    @EmbeddedId
    private FulfilmentOrderLinesKey key;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private int status;
}
```

Then you can add a repository with a method to return what you are looking for.

```
@Repository
public interface FulfilmentOrderLinesRepository extends JpaRepository<FulfilmentOrderLines, FulfilmentOrderLinesKey> {

    List<FulfilmentOrderLines> findAllByKeyOrderNumberLocationIdAndStatus(String locationId, int status);
}
```